# Why are my typescript interfaces being compiled to javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, interface

As I understand it, interfaces are only relevant in Typescript and the tsc compiler should be smart enough not to convert them to JS files in the final output. When I compile my code the interfaces are being compiled with it. Why is this?

### My simplified project structure

```
src/
  index.ts
  lib/
    EventClient.ts
  interfaces/
    EventClientConfig.ts
```

### What it compiles to

```
dist/
  index.js
  lib/
    EventClient.js
  interfaces/
    EventClientConfig.js
```

### My tsconfig.json

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "lib": ["ES6", "DOM"],
    "target": "ES2018",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "removeComments": true,
    "strict": true,
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"],
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "types": [
      "node",
      "jest-fetch-mock",
      "express",
      "reflect-metadata"
    ]
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["dist", "node_modules", "**/*spec.ts"]
}
```

### An interface

```js
export interface EventClientConfig {
  endpoint: string;
  authToken: string;
}
```

### How I'm using the interface

```js
import { EventClientConfig } from '../interfaces/EventClientConfig';

const config: EventClientConfig = {
  endpoint: '/api',
  authToken: '123456'
}
```

### What the interface is compiled to

```js
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
```

In the compiled code EventClient.js makes no actual reference to the EventClientConfig.js so it's definitely not required. Why is Typescript compiling the interface files to JS?

Comment: If you don't like this behavior you can use a declaration file.d.ts. Also, don't confuse a module with something it exports.

Comment: @AluanHaddad that solves problem. I renamed all the interface files so that they had a .d.ts suffix and they're no longer in the compiled directory. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 6):

This was solved thanks to @AluanHaddad who suggested using .d.ts declaration files. I have changed all my interface filenames so that they end with .d.ts and they are no longer included in the output.

Comment: is there any problem with the files being compiled to JS. If the ts file only contain types, it wont be used in runtime

Comment: @AlbertoS. it would unnecessarily bloat the bundle.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your questions is here [modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html)

> In TypeScript, just as in ECMAScript 2015, any file containing a top-level import or export is considered a module. Conversely, a file without any top-level import or export declarations is treated as a script whose contents are available in the global scope (and therefore to modules as well).